# How to get a nested document as object in mongoosastic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

i have a nodejs server with mongoosastic an try to get a nested search result as objects instead of only the indexes.

thats my code:

```
require('../server/serverInit');


var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var esclient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');

var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var esclient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: '127.0.0.1:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});
global.DBModel = {};
/**
 * StoreSchema
 * @type type
 */

var storeSchema = global.mongoose.Schema({
    Name: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
    Email: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
   .....
    _articles: {type: [articleSchema],
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: 'nested',
        es_include_in_parent: true}
});

/**
 * ArtikelSchema
 * @type Schema
 */

var articleSchema = new Schema({       
    Name: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
    Kategorie: String,
    ....
    _stores: {type: [storeSchema],
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: 'nested',
        es_include_in_parent: true}
});

storeSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: esclient
});
articleSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: esclient
});
global.DBModel.Artikel = global.mongoose.model('Artikel', articleSchema);

global.DBModel.Store = global.mongoose.model('Store', storeSchema);
```

when i now fire a search from the route "/search" which have this example code:

```
global.DBModel.Artikel.search({
                    query_string: {
                        query: "*"
                    }
                }, {
                    hydrate: true
                }, function (err, results) {
                    if (err)
                        return res.send(500, {error: err});
                    res.send(results);
                });
```

i get this result:

```
...
      {
        "_id": "56ab6b15352a43725a21bc92",
        "stores": [
          "56ab6b03352a43725a21bc91"
        ],
        "Name": "daaadd",
        "ArtikelNummer": "232",
        "__v": 0,
        "_stores": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How i can get directly a object instead of the id "56ab6b03352a43725a21bc91"?

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly add populate option to plugin options for indexing populated nested documents. In your case defining mongoosastic plugin like this may work:

```
storeSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: esclient,
    populate: [
        { path: '_articles', select: '_id Name Kategorie' }
    ]
});
articleSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: esclient,
    populate: [
        { path: '_stores', select: '_id Name Email' }
    ]
});
```

Also you should also specify `es_schema` inside field options like this:

```
var articleSchema = new Schema({       
    Name: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
    Kategorie: String,
    ....
    _stores: {type: [storeSchema],
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: 'nested',
        es_include_in_parent: true,
        es_schema: storeSchema
   }
});
```

See example here: https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#indexing-mongoose-references

Comment: When I add es_schema to point to storeSchema (similar schema), I get the following error. ```/node_modules/mongoosastic/lib/mapping-generator.js:56<br/> mapping[field].type = value.type <br/> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')```. I've been trying for a few hours now, still haven't figured out how to fix this crash.